# Full screen app on Linux with out desk top

Tags: linux, perl, graphics, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi, that I connect to via SSH. What I want to do is run a perl script that outputs to a full screen appliance via the HDMI port.

Eventually I would like to boot up direct to a script that outputs to the HDMI. But for now I want to be able to remote SSH to the pi while testing, and have the out put from the perl script to a connected screen.

I know I could do this via a desktop environment, but I just would like to know how to remain on the cli while a script outputs to a full screen display. I have only ever used text based scripts graphic is completely new to me. So simple outputting a full screen window to HDMI and plotting a dot in the middle would be a good base to build from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your computer's screen for testing purpose, use ssh with the -X option: it does X requests forwarding.

Using -X option will use your computer's (not r-pi's) X server in order to draw windows and other things.

Of course you must be running some sort of X server.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You may need to run the xhost command on the X-window server host to give the Pi access to your xhost.

Comment: Hi sorry, the set up is the HDMI output is connected to a tv and it's here I want to see the graphic output. At the moment the pi boots to a shell interface not to a x desktop. What I would like is for the pi to boot in to a basic X environment for the graphical output on the TV.

Comment: Now that sounds like the missing keyword I have been looking for :) I shall do as you suggest thank you :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Feel free to come back over and ask what you need :)